# UITableView - Multiple selection AND single selection

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode7

I have 2 sections in my UITableView.
I want the first section to allow multiple cell selection and the second section to allow only single selection.
I tried some code but didn't work very well.
Code in swift if possible. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you want the second section to deselect the first row when the second row is selected? Also, posting your existing code does help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could implement the table view's delegate methods:

`tableView(_:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:)`

and

`tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)`

...and determine (from `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.section`) if the relevant section supports single/multiple selection (this will depend on your data model's custom logic -e.g.: "Section `0` supports multiple selection but section `1` does not"), and if it only supports single selection, check whether there is already a row selected (by accessing `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows`).

If there is a selected row already, you can:

1. Return  `false` from `tableView(_:shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:)`, and
2. Do nothing (just `return`) from `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` (I'm not sure if this method is actually called when you return `false` from `shouldHighlight...`, so perhaps check it).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply try this. This solution works for me perfectly. Give it a try maybe worked for others...

Swift-4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
    else {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How will you deselect a cell in section 2 once selected?

Answer (score 2):

This is easily achievable in two lines as follows: **(Swift 4)**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if sectionAllowsMultipleSelection {
        if let indexPathsInSection = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.filter ({ $0.section == indexPath.section && $0.row != indexPath.row }) {
            for selectedPath in indexPathsInSection {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedPath, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selected row in section 2 to be the new selected row, this might work for you. Else, go with @NicolasMiari's answer.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        for i in 0..tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) - 1 {
            let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: indexPath.section))!
            if (i == indexPath.row) {
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                cell.selected = false
            }
            else {
                cell.accessoryType = .None
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        //Do whatever for the first section
    }
}
```

Not very elegant, but hopefully it will give you an idea.