# Single and Multiple Selection in same tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView which has two different sections, one for single selection and one more for multiple selection. I also built two different custom cells for the same. I am able to get multiple selection right,but not the single selection.

I am using the override provided `setSelected` by the tableView Cell for both single and multiple Selection.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        if selected {
            //make label red
            }
        } else {
            //make label white
        }

    }
```

However, the problem which i am facing is that when I click on multipleSelection section's cell, the `setSelected` ovveride of my singleSelectionCell gets called and it marks the label white. If a cell is already selected in singleSelection I need to keep it that way.

I looked at this answer but I am not sure how to go about this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32857181/4863339

can someone please help me in rectifying this problem?

Comment: selected property of cell is not work as section selection, you need to maintain the state of selection with `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Thank you replying. Correct me if I am wrong, but I did try doing something in `cellForRowAt`, but it does not get called when I click on cell. Could you please elaborate more on how to save the state?

Comment: You can create one instance property of type `IndexPath` inside your `ViewController` for single selection section and for multiple selection section create array of `IndexPath` and add/remove object in `didSelectRowAt` method.

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Yeah! Nirav is right. You have to follow this. It is the only proper method. And in `cellforrow` you have to put condition check which cell is selected or not. And reload table after each selection/deselection.

Comment: Big answer, but i'm u giving little trick, create `NSMutableDictionary` of how much is your data for managing your bool.

Comment: @NiravD - I am not understanding as to how to implement this. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Check my answer, Also now there is no need to override `setSelected` method inside your custom tableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want you need to maintain the state of selection of your cell, for single selection Section declare one instance property of type `IndexPath?` and for multiple selection section declare one instance property of type `[IndexPath]`. After that compare this property in `cellForRowAt` method and change its value in `didSelectRowAt` method.

**Edit:** With Custom Object you can try like this way, With your sectionItem Class create one property `selected` of type Bool and use that to select multiple or single item

SO your class should be look like this.

```
class Section {
    var isMultiple: Bool
    var title: String
    var items: [Item]

    init(isMultiple: Bool, title: String, items: [Item]) {
        self.isMultiple = isMultiple
        self.title = title
        self.items = items
    }
}

class Item {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    //To maintain selected state
    var selected: Bool = false

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Now with `cellForRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt` it should goes like this way.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
    let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
    if sections[indexPath.section].isMultiple {
        //For multiple selection
        if item.selected {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark //Or make label red
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none //Or make label white
        }
    }
    else {
        //For single selection
        if item.selected {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark //Or make label red
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = .none //Or make label white
        }
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if sections[indexPath.section].isMultiple {
        //For multiple selection
        let item = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
        item.selected = !item.selected
        sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row] = item
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    else {
        //For multiple selection
        let items = sections[indexPath.section].items

        if let selectedItemIndex = items.indices.first(where: { items[$0].selected }) {
            sections[indexPath.section].items[selectedItemIndex].selected = false
            if selectedItemIndex != indexPath.row {
                sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].selected = true
            }
        }
        else {
            sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].selected = true
        }
        self.tableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Don't get your above comment? "I am segregating my cells as follows"?

Comment: Thanks for getting back! Right now I have multiple sections in my tableView which I am segregating like so..

`return self.sections[section].sectionItems!.count`

I can also differentiate multiple/single selection of cells from the API response like so 

`let section = self.sections[indexPath.section]`

`if section.isMultiple {
let multipleSelectioncell = tableview.cellForRowAt(indexpath)
} else {
let singleSelectionCell = tableview.cellForRowAt(indexpath)
}`

now how would I keep track of selected rows and unselected rows for single selection in `didSelectRow` ?

Comment: Are you comparing String? Is `sectionItems` is array of String?

Comment: No, they are array of objects. I am passing the object to my custom cell to handle to view for those cells.

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha So the object inside `sectionItems` having same reference with your tableView datasource array right? OR they are having different reference, then are you having some unique id/key with your custom objects.

Comment: Yes, my sectionItems comes from Sections array from the API (which is mapped after getting the response from API)

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Are you having more than two sections? Means you don't know how many sections you are having in tableView?

Comment: The number of sections depends upon the number of objects recieved from API. So the API structure looks something lie this. There is a main array of objects, which is my total number of sections and inside of each object I have another array of objects. something like this. 

`{
  "res": [
    {
      "Id": 25,
      "multipleSelectionEnabled": false,
      "Name": "sectionName",
      "sectionItems": [
        {
          "Id": 6,
          "Name": "cell 1"
        },
        {
          "Id": 19,
          "Name": "cell 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Are sectionItems also array of custom object same like section?

Comment: I did follow some of suggestions and it seems to be working now. Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Welcome mate:)

Comment: I'm having problems again on this. from where are you getting `selected` property.
For Eg:
`sections[indexPath.section].items[selectedItemIndex].selected = false`

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Don't get your comment can you describe your problem in detail.

Comment: can we please move this over to chat? so that I can describe my problem in detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136303/discussion-between-nirav-d-and-abhishek-harsha).

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha Welcome mate :)