# UITableView sections with single and multiple selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**How do I make an UITableView which allows sections to either have single or multiple selection?**

I have a single `UITableView` with multiple sections. I want some sections to allow multiple selections and some to only allow a single selection. This is what I currently have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    // Get the current question
    if var question = self.questions[indexPath.section] as? MultipleChoiceQuestion {
        // If question allows multiple selection set a checkmark and update question with selected answer
        if question.hasMultiValue {
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            question.givenAnswer = question.answers[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            // Question is single selection only. This entire part goes wrong.
            if let givenAnswerIsEmpty = question.givenAnswer {
                cell?.accessoryType = .none
            } else {
                self.questions[indexPath.section].givenAnswer = question.answers[indexPath.row]
                cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My objects all have the property `hasMultiValue` which indicates if a section should allow multiple selections or not. They also have the property `givenAnswer` which could be seen as a "isSelected" flag. The code above only works for multi selection.

I've been searching around for a solution. There are a few questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857091/uitableview-multiple-selection-and-single-selection) one but the solution involves using the delegate method `didDeselectRowAt`. This method won't get called unless I physically deselect the current cell which is not what I want.

What I do want is for example:

If you select row1 and change your mind to row2, you should be able to select row2 which automatically deselects row1.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't try `willSelectRowAt`?

You can try this code, this is tested on a table view controller

```
var selectedItemInSection1: Int?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    // Just return the same index path if the section was not the second one
    guard indexPath.section == 1 else { return indexPath }

    // Get the previously selected item, and deselect it
    if let prev = selectedItemInSection1 {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: prev, section: 1), animated: true)
    }

    // Save the newly selected item index, to be deselected when other is selected in the same section
    selectedItemInSection1 = indexPath.row
    // Select the item
    return indexPath
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard indexPath.section == 1 else { return }

    // If it is in the second section, indicate that no item is selected now
    selectedItemInSection1 = nil
}
```